# PlotlyJS.jl LaTeX integration in VS Code

Tags: plotly, julia, julia-plots

How can I use LaTeX rendering in VS Code using PlotlyJS.jl?

How can I use LaTeX rendering in VS Code using PlotlyJS.jl?
Using this code with Julia v1.10 in VS Code:

```
using PlotlyJS 
using LaTeXStrings 
tr = scatter(x=1:10, y=sin.(1:10)) 
layout = Layout(title=L"\omega")
Plot(tr, layout)
```

I get this [plot output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BfMCe.png).

At the [Plotly page](https://plotly.com/julia/LaTeX/) it is stated, that i need to load MathJax library into my environment. 
All the answers I found were either using Jupyter or Plots.jl. Is there a simple way to do this with PlotlyJS.jl in VS Code?